# Camunda Modeler - translation/localisation

Tags: camunda

I have simple question regarding modeler. Is it possible to change default modeler language? Modeler directory contains folder "locales" but I don't see in documentation or in top menu option to change default (english) language.

Regards,
Maciej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From camunda forum

> You cannot localize the modeler at this time and we do not plan to add
>   I18N in the near future.

Look [Internationalize (i18n) modeler issue](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-modeler/issues/478)